# JQuery select value output value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to output the value in option in the input value field.
So if i select red i wish to output red in the input value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").click(function(){
        $("input:text").val($this);
    });
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input" value="">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: `$("input:text").val($(this).val());` - there is no `$this` in the change event handler, you can get the select input's value using `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [.change()](https://api.jquery.com/change/) not `click()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $("input[type=text]").val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="red">red</option>
  <option value="black">black</option>
  <option value="blue">blue</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input" value="">
<div id="output"></div>
```